# How to I find and kill a DnD?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, do-not-disturb

On my Nexus 6P, Android 7.1.2, I once entered a Do Not Disturb setting which started at 0450 local time. I deleted that, but since the 7.1.2 upgrade, it has returned. It even occurs in Safe mode. How do I find it, and kill it, dead, with a stake through its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DND is not a cron job... It's "embedded" in the OS databases. Unless someone knows exactly what file and where, assuming it's ASCII editable file, a factory reset might be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

If you rooted great if not that's okay.
Download terminal emulator and type `top` you will see a list of of processes find the one you are looking for and follow the on screen instructions on how to kill it.

Comment: -1: as specified by @acejavelin, the abovementioned setting is stored in a database. While your answer might fit a GNU/Linux system, it's not targeted to Android.

Comment: Android is based off of Linux it does apply

Comment: Android merely has a modified Linux kernel. Since each app has its own context, databases and code, the Linux-like binaries are rarely called.